# How do I do fast scoring in H2o over python streams?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to use a H2o model to score some data which is in a python process. The data is not available to me in a file but rather a stream. I want to do something like this in python.

```
scores = [model.predict(line) for line in data]
```

where data is some generic iterable; for example a generator.

This isn't possible as written because the data is in python and first must be moved to the H2o JVM. I don't want to read the whole stream into memory and pass it as a H2oFrame. In fact, it could have infinite length.

I could do

```
scores = [model.predict(h2o.H2oFrame([line]) for line in data]
```

but this is very slow because every call to H2oFrame has to generate a new parser. The creation of the parser (I assume the creation, not the actual parsing but I don't know for sure) takes 25.2 ms which is far too slow to iterate over streams with millions of items.

Is there any way to make this fast? For example, can you pass in the parser rather than have it create a new one each time?

I realize there are other ways to do this such as scoring with the POJO in Java code but I'd like to do it in Python. Also don't want any heavy-weight solutions like Spark streaming. I already tried creating a FIFO and reading from that as if it was a real file but that didn't work.

Comment: What about breaking it down into smaller batches and scoring say 10,000 samples at a time?

Comment: Yeah, I can do it in mini-batches like that but you shouldn't have to.

Comment: for you'll have to do something like the form you posted because h2o works on frames, otherwise a POJO/MOJO is required.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius -- I would consider instantiating a MOJO or POJO object and calling it from python.